# How to set the dlls in path for eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, java-native-interface, eclipse-rcp

I am building an eclipse rcp plugin. It needs to load a native dll. I have the dlls in the path env var, iam using windows 7.
I have also checked with System.getProperty("java.library.path") and i can see the folder in which the dlls are present. But still when i execute it i get the following error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.cordys.debug.nom.node.Node.writeBytes(III)[B
    at com.cordys.debug.nom.node.Node.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at com.cordys.debug.nom.node.Node.write(Node.java:137)
    at com.cordys.debug.nom.node.Node.write(Node.java:103)
    at com.cordys.debug.nom.node.Node.writeToString(Node.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.actions.PopupDisplayNodeAction.displayStringResult(PopupDisplayNodeAction.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.actions.DisplayAction$2.detailComputed(DisplayAction.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JavaDetailFormattersManager$EvaluationListener.valueToString(JavaDetailFormattersManager.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JavaDetailFormattersManager.resolveFormatter(JavaDetailFormattersManager.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JavaDetailFormattersManager.access$1(JavaDetailFormattersManager.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JavaDetailFormattersManager$2.run(JavaDetailFormattersManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread$ThreadJob.run(JDIThread.java:2756)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Anyone out there have a clue how to set the dlls in path for eclipse plugin?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here [Using shared libraries with Eclipse RCP](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/08/18/using-shared-libraries-with-eclipse-rcp/) you can find a nice instruction how to do it - assuming that you can build feature that contains your plug-in.

Comment: I donot want to build a feature, i just want my plugin to load the dlls. Also its fine for me if the user has to set the Path. As i already mentioned i have also checked with System.getProperty("java.library.path") and i can see the folder in which the dlls are present. But still when i execute it i get the unsatisfied link error.